# How do I groupby a dict by one of the keys?

Tags: python

I need to group a input dictionary based on two keys and return each group as part of a list of dictionaries. For e.g.,

```
data = {
    'name': ['A', 'C', 'B', 'B'],
    'tag': [13, 26, 13, 3],
    'id': [234, 235, 236, 237],
    'values': [[1, 3, 3], [1, 2, 1], [1, 2, 3], [1, 1, 1]],
}
```

I can use `defaultdict` to do the subsetting and to return one key of the dict pretty easily. For e.g., this will return a list of dicts grouped by `data['name']`:

Without using pandas (dataset is too big), how can I groupby one or more tags (say, `by=['name', 'tag']`) and return a list of dicts?

Edit: Expected output can be a list of dicts:

```
[
{'name': 'A', tag: 13, 'id': 234, 'values': [1, 3, 3]}, 
{'name': 'C', tag: 26, 'id': 235, 'values': [1, 2, 1]},
{'name': 'B', tag: 13, 'id': 236, 'values': [1, 2, 3]},
{'name': 'B', tag:  3, 'id': 237, 'values': [1, 1, 2]}
]
```

or a dict of dicts:

```
{
('A', 13): {'id': 234, 'values': [1, 3, 3]}, 
('C', 26): {'id': 235, 'values': [1, 2, 1]},
('B', 13): {'id': 236, 'values': [1, 2, 3]},
('B',  3): {'id': 237, 'values': [1, 1, 2]}
}
```

Comment: please add expected output for sample input

Comment: So, you want `{ ('A',13'): {id:234, values:[1.3.3]}, ('C',26): {'id': 235, 'values': [1,2,1]}}`?

Comment: @TimRoberts correct.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's actually a lot easier than it might seem:

```
{(n, t): {'id': i, 'values': vs} for n, t, i, vs in zip(*data.values())}
```

Once you zip the 4 values together, it's just a matter of

1. iterating over the resulting sequence of tuples,
2. unpacking each tuple and
3. constructing the desired key/value pair from the unpacked values.

If there is any concern over the order in which the 4 `list` values will be returned by `data.values()`, you can be more explicit:

```
from operator import itemgetter

# g(data) == (data['name'], data['tag'], data['id'], data['values'])
g = itemgetter('name', 'tag', 'id', 'values')
result = {(n, t): {'id': i, 'values': vs} for n, t, i, vs in zip(*g(data))}
```

Comment: that's nifty! Can you generalize it for many keys in `data`? I have about 20.

Comment: `zip` will produce tuples with as many values as there are keys in the original dict. For a large number, it might be easier to leave the tuple packed and index it when constructing the key/value pairs. E.g., `{(t[0], t[1]): {'id': t[2], 'values': t[3]} for t in zip(*data.values())}`.

Comment: Thanks! The `zip(*g(data))` part is slick. I love that you used dict comprehension.